# Empty loop meaning in a timer code using C

Tags: c, embedded, avr

```
void Tmr_Wait1us (uint16_t delay) {
    uint16_t i;
    TCNT0 = 0;      // will start to count from 0 up to 255 (if 8-bit timer)
    for (i = 0; i < delay / 256; i++)
        while (TCNT0 < 255)         
            ;   
    while (TCNT0 <= delay % 256)
        ;
}
```

This code is used to set a timer to wait precise amount of time, to be applied to AVR-Atmega32a , I can't understand what the empty loops does here? also what the second loop does?

Comment: Ambiguous question; there are three loops, two of which are empty.  Be clear about which loops you are referring.

Comment: It is not a good method of delay; the 8 bit timer will wrap from 255 to zero, but the loop tests while `TCNT0 < 255`,which is false only when `TCNT0` is exactly 255, this state could easily be missed if an interrupt occurs and takes longer than a single count to process, Making the delay non-deterministically longer than intended. Rather the timer-wrap interrupt should be used to increment a counter, and that counter polled rather than `TCNT0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They look like busy waits. They block until the condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

`TCNT0` is the current timer count for timer 0, a 8-bit timer. Since it counts asynchronously from your code, it will increment even if the CPU is in a spin wait.

But since avr-libc provides fairly precise spin waits in [`util/delay.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) you are usually better off using those instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < delay; i++)
  _delay_us(1);
```

Comment: The first `delay/256` loops count until `TCNT0` equals 255. The last loop counts for the remainder `delay%256`. The code will fail if the timer rolls over between loop tests.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of delay generated depends on the prescalar of the source clock set for the timer0
Both the loops just block the until the TCNT0 counts reaches a specific value
However this is not a good way to implement a delay loop
Instead of counting the point when TCNT0 reaches 255 the user should check for the overflow bit TOV0  in TIFR register to set.
You can refer to the application note from atmel on Mega timers http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2505-Setup-and-Use-of-AVR-Timers_ApplicationNote_AVR130.pdf